# Magento links are not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, magento

I have a magento theme installed on a folder: http://mysite.com/mag/

On the main folder, mysite.com it's running a website on Zen Cart, so I created a folder called "mag" where I installed magento.
It worked until now..
Only the first page is loading when I access mysite.com/mag/, but when I click on a diffrent page I-m sent to the index page from: mysite.com (and the url showed is: http://mysite.com/mag/page-like-this.html)

So where is the problem?
It worked before, and right now it doesn't work any more..

Comment: Until now.. .WHat has changed? DId you modify something? Try to be clearer.

Comment: I haven't changed anything, that's why I don't know exactly where to look, but i've seen in the main folder that there appeared some folders/pages like: Survey.php, Toolbar.php, Security.php, Window.php, YtdStart.php and folder Grid. (nothing in error log)

Comment: Very good chance youhave been hacked then. Some script might of created all those files and modified your index.php. Google "my website was hacked" and see if you can recognise something.

Comment: I was hopeing it might be something else.. :D

Comment: Well it might. But if files appeared that you did not put there I am affraid this is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as was discovered trough our comments you have most probably been hacked in some way. There are a lot of steps to go trough to clean a website and its impossible for us to tell you what to look for without knowing what kind of attack you where a victim of.

But, you can safely delete all those .html files since they should not be part of magento/zend framework. Also look for weird javascript that would be encrypted. One very long string of minimized javascript somewhere at the end probably of all the html files and probably your main index.php file.

There is a lot of ressources online to help you I suggest googling "magento hacked" or some such thing.

Good luck!

Here's a stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334303/php-web-application-magento-hacked-what-does-this-hacker-code-do) about some such hacks on magento.